# AttributeError: module 'pandas.plotting' has no attribute '_matplotlib'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am generating a graph using pandas. When I run my script locally, I get this error:
`AttributeError: module 'pandas.plotting' has no attribute '_matplotlib'`

I installed pandas for both my user and system. The operating system is WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04.

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_multi(data, cols=None, spacing=.1, **kwargs):

    from pandas import plotting

    # Get default color style from pandas - can be changed to any other color list
    if cols is None: cols = data.columns
    if len(cols) == 0: return
    colors = getattr(getattr(plotting, '_matplotlib').style, '_get_standard_colors')(num_colors=len(cols))


    # First axis
    print(data.loc[:, cols[0]])
    ax = data.loc[:, cols[0]].plot(label=cols[0], color=colors[0], **kwargs)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel=cols[0])
    lines, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

    for n in range(1, len(cols)):
        # Multiple y-axes
        ax_new = ax.twinx()
        ax_new.spines['right'].set_position(('axes', 1 + spacing * (n - 1)))
        data.loc[:, cols[n]].plot(ax=ax_new, label=cols[n], color=colors[n % len(colors)], **kwargs)
        ax_new.set_ylabel(ylabel=cols[n])

        # Proper legend position
        line, label = ax_new.get_legend_handles_labels()
        lines += line
        labels += label

    ax.legend(lines, labels, loc=0)
    return ax
```

This worked on a University lab machine. Not sure why it's not working locally.

Comment: Can you share the version of `matplotlib` and `pandas`

Comment: Here's all my pandas dependencies.
https://hatebin.com/tkwpvqmoqt

Comment: Did you check the version match in your university lab? Im pretty sure its the verion difference.